# Update table (rows) Access 2007 and C# 2010

Tags: c#, database, ms-access-2007

So this is probably the most naive question but that is what questions are for I guess;
Then, my issue is that I have no idea on how to connect Visual C# Express 2010 to Access 2007 and do the typical insert, update, delete, search in an application in C#, I have just learned the basics (finished a console tutorial, which I believe is more than enought, having previous background of VB6 using access 97), and I have been searching here and in the web, but the only thing I could find where the msdn tutorials which I dind't find really clear.
So in my app I just need to link comboboxes, query those values to obtain new ones, do calculations and then store in arrays (and maybe show these in datagrids as well as edit them from said datagrids, which is a bit more complicated I guess) and finally store them in various tables, but I haven't really found a strong (or most likely simple) manual that will guide me to create the typical app insert, update, delete using winforms.
Do you guys have any good links in order to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Also, I'm using Windows.Identity and Windows.Principal to check the username and if it is a member of the security group that is able to modify the database, so I guess BD security essentials wouldn't be such a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code

Here link about string connection : http://www.connectionstrings.com/access-2007

```
var query = "...";
var connectionString = "...";

    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        // The insertSQL string contains a SQL statement that
        // inserts a new row in the source table.
        using(var command = new OleDbCommand(query))
        {    
        // Set the Connection to the new OleDbConnection.
        command.Connection = connection;

        // Open the connection and execute the insert command.
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        // The connection is automatically closed when the
        // code exits the using block.
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the link, I actually added the DB trough the VS wizard, would you happen to have a link in how to link comboboxes?